# How to make correlation more efficient

Tags: performance-tuning

I've defined a correlation function which does the following:

- Take two data sets $d_1$ and $d_2$ which are the same size and shape
- Pad $d_2$ with zeroes (to avoid non-positive indices in the next step)
- Crop $d_2$ to a region the size and shape of the original image but displaced from the centre by $r_n$ rows and $c_n$ columns
- Multiply $d_1\,\!^\ast$ by the displaced $d_2$
- Normalise the result by overlapping area (to avoid the possibility that a large displacement will result in a small correlation simply because there are not enough pixels rather than because the correlation is actually low)

Here's the code ($rows$ is the number of rows in each data set, and $cols$ is the number of columns in each data set):

```
corr[d1_,d2_,rn_,cn_]:=Total[
                        Total[
                         Conjugate[d1]ArrayPad[
                          d2,{{Length[d2]},{Length[Transpose[d2]]}}
                         ][[Length[d1]+1+rn;;2Length[d1]+rn,
                            Length[Transpose[d1]]+1+cn;;2Length[Transpose[d1]]+cn]]
                        ]
                       ]/((rows-rn)(cols-cn));
```

(Before anyone says anything, yes, I do know Mathematica already has a built-in correlation function. I made my own correlation function because I didn't want to spend a long time checking that Mathematica's function did exactly what I wanted and possibly troubleshooting it. I create a lot of zeroes, sure, but in the end I'm just multiplying $rows\times cols$ pairs of numbers and adding the results together.)

Given two data sets, I then do this for different values of $r_n$ and $c_n$ and create a correlation map:

```
corrdata=ParallelTable[corr[data1,data2,rn,cn],{rn,-100,100},{cn,-150,150}]
```

My problem is that I have big data sets and this takes a long time. I want to run this correlation function on 10,000 data sets. If running it on data sets with 80,000 pixels and making correlation maps with 60,501 pixels takes 15 minutes on my computer, running it 10,000 times is going to take 104 days.

Is there a way to make this (a lot) quicker?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a start, `Length[Transpose[d2]` should be replaced by `Dimensions[d1][[2]]2`. Or would you turn an elefant onto its back just for counting its legs?

Comment: Don't use `ArrayPad`; instead extract the correct rows and colums of `d1` and `d2` with `Part`. Having extracted them into, say `a1` and `a2`, use `Tr[Conjugate[a1].a2]` or `Flatten[Conjugate[a1]].Flatten[a2]` instead multiplying and `Total`.

Comment: Why not use the built in function ListCorrelate? Since you are worried about efficiency, there's a good chance it will be faster.

Comment: Edit: Should be `Tr[ConjugateTranspose[a1].a2]`, but `Flatten`ing is problably faster.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for the advice. Will try and get back to you.

Comment: @bills Simply because I didn't want to make sure that Mathematica's built-in correlation function was doing exactly what I wanted it to do. I figured it would be faster to write my own function than to test and troubleshoot Mathematica's.

Comment: Also, would working with real numbers and getting rid of `Conjugate` help at all?

Comment: OK, I made all of those edits (using `Dimensions` instead of transposing the matrices, using ranges instead of padding, flattening the matrices into vectors, and not conjugating *d1*). I'm using `Min` and `Max` to ensure the index doesn't go below 1 or above *rows* or *cols* (otherwise Mathematica will complain). It's been running for 45 minutes and it hasn't finished. I think it's safe to say it isn't faster than my original code.

Comment: Would please provide example data?

Comment: I think just `ListCorrelate[d1, d2, {-1, 1}, 0]` would be orders of magnitude faster, although you will have to also determine the normalization, which can be determined by replacing `d1` and `d2` with matrices of 1s.

Comment: OK, I must have had an error of some sort, because I re-ran it with more than twice as much data and it took 152 seconds. Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you insist on not using [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate). Here is a version of your code that uses [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate):

```
listC[d1_,d2_]:=Module[{r, c},
    {r,c}=Dimensions[d1];
    Divide[
        ListCorrelate[Conjugate[d1],d2,{-1,1},0],
        N@Outer[Times,Reverse@Range[2r-1],Reverse@Range[2c-1]]
    ]
]
```

*(by the way, I think your computation of the denominator is flawed, but I use the same denominator so that the outputs can be compared).* And, here is a comparison with your code in the OP:

```
d1 = RandomComplex[1+I, {20,30}];
d2 = RandomComplex[1+I, {20,30}];

r1 = listC[d1, d2]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Table[corr[d1,d2,rn,cn], {rn,-19,19}, {cn,-29,29}]; //AbsoluteTiming

Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance=4}, r1 == r2]
```

> {0.000654, Null}
>
> {1.13723, Null}
>
> True

*(I needed to lower the tolerance due to numeric fuzz)*. As you can see, [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate) is already over 1000 times faster. Here is an example using larger matrices:

```
d1 = RandomComplex[1+I, {1000,1000}];
d2 = RandomComplex[1+I, {1000,1000}];

listC[d1, d2]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.704561, Null}

Comment: I don't know why people insist on using Mathematica's built-in functions. I clearly stated my reasons not to want to use them right from the beginning, yet I keep receiving suggestions to use them. I appreciate the help, but not the insistence that I do things I've already said I don't want to do.

Comment: My denominator is indeed wrong. I should have used `Abs[rn]` and `Abs[cn]` rather than `rn` and `cn`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try `ListCorrelate` after my current code finishes running.